# Proving irrationality by contradiction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I find solving proving irrationals with even numbers inside the square root like $\sqrt{2}$ easy which gives us even q and even p but when it comes to odd square roots or just straight out unknowns like $\sqrt{pq}$(yes they are 2 distinct prime numbers) i follow the same procedure of $\frac{q^2}{p^2}$ then i stop there and i dont see anything to follow up with I want to know if there is a general rule of thumb I can use to prove irrationality by contradiction

Comment: There isn't a "general rule of thumb" for proving irrationality. It is _difficult_. However, square roots are a special case, and they are easier (the classic $\sqrt2$ proof works almost without changes, using $p\mid n^2\implies p\mid n$). For your specific proof, if you provide us some more details, it will be much easier for us to understand where you are stuck and what you should do next.

Comment: Proving irrationality is notoriously difficult.  For example here is a link with several proofs of the irrationality of $\pi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational

How many can you follow?  Yes, there are some easy ones such as $\sqrt 2$ but these are the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to showing irrationality of roots, assuming you have proved this already, is to consider the [Rational Roots Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

For example, let $a$ be a non-perfect square natural number. Then $\sqrt{a}$ is definitely a root of the polynomial $x^2 - a = 0$

Let's assume that $\sqrt{a}$ is rational.

The Rational Roots Theorem states that any possible rational roots of this polynomial must be a divisor of $a$ (positive or negative). Once you show that none of these options are roots, we must have that $\sqrt{a}$ isn't a  rational root, a contradiction